# Obtaining and sampling from the posterior predictive of a naive Bayes classifier

Tags: bayesian, classification, naive-bayes, posterior

I have trained a naive Bayes classifier with on a dataset with a dichotomous outcome and multinomial attributes (predictors).

I managed to get a Maximum *a posteriori* (MAP) estimate which is good enough to determine class membership of a given instance of attributes.

However, to calculate things like the Highest Density Interval (HDI) I would need to get the posterior distribution rather than a point estimate. How can I do that?

And more specifically, how could I sample from that distribution? (via BUGS for instance).

Any help is appreciated